# Opening a new tab and filling page with innerHTML of parent page using javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Is there a way to make a new tab display the `innerHTML` from the parent page?
Say if I initialized a variable like so `var dat = document.body.innerHTML;` .

Then I did something like:

```
var pop = window.open();
pop.innerHTML = dat;
```

But this returns a blank page.

Is this a scope issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pop.document.body.innerHTML = dat;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
pop.document.write(dat);
```